# Exp-resso store email template translation

Tags: expresso-store, multi-language

I'm using Exp:presso store on a webshop. This webshop has multiple languages which I did with Publisher.

Now I want to send the customer emails in their native language. Or at least, the language they also used on the website when they ordered something.

Now using publisher phrases in the order confirmation email is working fine, the email is send with translations. This only doesn't work for the Subject, there it will put the phrase in: `{phrase:email_subject}` => {phrase:email_subject}

It also doesn't work for all other emails that are send. Probably because it doesn't know which language it should use.

Is there a way to do what I want? Send emails in the right language? Maybe with something like publisher? Or should I make a email template for each language? And how would I then trigger the right email template?

Answer (score 2):

Since Publisher doesn't technically have Store support or vise-versa you won't be able to use Publisher for your additional emails directly.

You could write an extension that would allow you to either set a custom order status for each language during checkout, which would allow you to assign an email template for their language to that order status. This will probably give you the most flexibility in the long term.

Alternatively you could set a [order_customX](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#custom_order_fields) field during the checkout with the language code from Publisher. So in your checkout template you would want to have something along the lines of:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
 <input type="hidden" name="order_custom1" value="{publisher:current_language_code}">
 Other checkout fields
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Then in your email template you could use conditionals to show specific content based upon the language value store in order_customX

```
{if order_custom1 == "en"}
 Show content in English
{/if}

{if order_custom1 == "es"}
 Lets have some Spanish text here
{/if}
```

The only issue that you are going to have with this is that I don't think that the Subject field has full template parsing so I am not sure if you could use the conditionals to show the correct subject.

Having said that I would highly recommend that you goto Store's Feature Request page and vote for [Multiple Language Support](https://www.exp-resso.com/support/feature-requests) to be added to Store.